# C++ evaluate constexpr template array values at compile time

Tags: c++, expression, constants, constexpr, compile-time

I'm creating an array of packed chars at compile time, but c++ is telling me that the expression must have a constant value -- cannot evaluate value of incomplete "gradient<256U>".

I'm trying to embed a color gradient inside my code from code.

```cpp
template<unsigned S>
struct gradient {
  constexpr gradient() : arr() {
    for (auto i = 0; i < S; i++)
      for (auto j = 0; j < S; j++)
        arr[i + j * S] = ((i % 256) << 24) | ((j % 256) << 16) | (((i * j) % 256) << 8) | 255;
  }

  unsigned arr[S * S];
};

constexpr auto g0 = gradient<255>(); // ok
constexpr auto g1 = gradient<256>(); // error
constexpr auto g2 = gradient<1024>(); // error
```

All of a sudden I can't create my gradient struct with higher values then 255. But why?

Comment: same behaviour.. with different types

Comment: Running this with `clang` yields a diagnostic only on the 1024 case, that `constexpr evaluation hit maximum step limit; possible infinite loop?`. It sounds like this is just caused by the amount of iterations of the `for` loop. If this is the case, I imagine it would be fixable by a compile-flag.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? It works for me in C++14 using gcc

Comment: In general there's little to no benefit for compiling that kind of array in compile-time? Why? Because usually you would create this object only once / twice, hence minimal benefit. Maybe just ditch constexpr and let optimizer do it's job?

Comment: That solved the problem! But still I don't know why g++ or clang cant compile this code...

Comment: g++ 8.3 was able to compile the code for me with -std=c++14

Comment: @Michael: "*But still I don't know why g++ or clang cant compile this code... *" You don't know why a compiler might be loath to execute code that may continue infinitely? The Halting Problem cannot be solved, so there's no way for a compiler to *know* if a piece of code will terminate. The only option to prevent infinite loops is to pick an arbitrary limit.

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to constexpr and didn't understand what it did and the halting problem.